# How to configure my buildForm for a OneToMany relationship?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to make a nested Form, embed a collection of forms inside a form. 
i have problem with the buildForm.

I'm trying to add a formType in a other form type in my case to add educations to my CurriculumVitae form.

- One CurriculumVitae has Many Educations.
- Many Education have One CurriculumVitae.

im getting this error message:

> Expected argument of type "array or (\Traversable and \ArrayAccess)",
>   "string" given

CurriculumVitae Entity:

```
/**
 * CurriculumVitae
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="curriculum_vitae")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="GE\CandidatBundle\Repository\CurriculumVitaeRepository")
 */
class CurriculumVitae
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GE\CandidatBundle\Entity\Education", mappedBy="curriculumVitae", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_education")
     */
    protected $educations;
/**
 * Add education
 *
 * @param \GE\CandidatBundle\Entity\Education $education
 *
 * @return CurriculumVitae
 */
public function addEducation(\GE\CandidatBundle\Entity\Education $education)
{
    $this->educations[] = $education;
    $education->setCurriculumVitae($this);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove education
 *
 * @param \GE\CandidatBundle\Entity\Education $education
 */
public function removeEducation(\GE\CandidatBundle\Entity\Education $education)
{
    $this->educations->removeElement($education);
}
}
```

Education Entity:

```
/**
 * Education
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="education")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="GE\CandidatBundle\Repository\EducationRepository")
 */
class Education
{
    ...
    /**
     * Many Education have One CurriculumVitae.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GE\CandidatBundle\Entity\CurriculumVitae", inversedBy="educations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="curriculumVitae_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $curriculumVitae;
}
```

CurriculumVitaeType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('educations',
                CollectionType::class, [
                    'entry_type' => EducationType::class,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'prototype' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'label' => 'Educations:'
                ]
            )
        ;
    }
```

CurriculumVitaeController:

```
class CurriculumVitaeController extends Controller
{
    ...
    public function editAction(Request $request, CurriculumVitae $curriculumVitae)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($curriculumVitae);
        $editForm = $this->createForm('GE\CandidatBundle\Form\CurriculumVitaeType', $curriculumVitae);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('cv_edit', array('id' => $curriculumVitae->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('curriculumvitae/edit.html.twig', array(
            'curriculumVitae' => $curriculumVitae,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's a problem with the constructor or what?

In my CurriculumVitae Entity:

```
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->objectifs = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->educations = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->experiences = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->formations = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->competences = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->dateAjout = new \Datetime();
    $this->etat = false;
    $this->disponibilite = false;
}
```

May be that the problem is here, when we need to nest a single form more than once i mean with which relationships?

Comment: hello, i need help.

Comment: OneToMany side does not have dedicated "Column", so try this `class CurriculumVitae
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GE\CandidatBundle\Entity\Education", mappedBy="curriculumVitae", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $educations;`

Comment: It is the same line that I put. what is wrong with my code?

Comment: for the addition I could not display the education form and for the modification I had this error: Expected argument of type "array or (\Traversable and \ArrayAccess)", "string" given

Comment: When you need to nest a single form more than once?

Comment: Hello, why there is no help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry,

I found my problem.

1) $candidatId should be $candidat. we are not storing ids in the entity but rather a reference to $candidat.

2) There is no column for education ids in CurriculumVitae. The    relationship is stored in each individual Education entity.

3) There is no need to @ORM\Column(name="id_education").

and i added a JoinColumn to $idCurriculumVitae

```
/**
 * @var CurriculumVitae
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GE\CandidatBundle\Entity\CurriculumVitae")
         *@ORM\JoinColumn(name="curriculumVitae_id",referencedColumnName="id",onDelete="SET NULL")
         */
        private $idCurriculumVitae;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a many to one related entities and every time I create a new `CurriculumVitae` entity which is related to `Candidat` entity the column `candidat_id_id` is null.

Only the entity `CurriculumVitae` is successfully created and persisted except the Candidat id in the data datatable.

**CurriculumVitae** table:

```
id | titre | candidat_id_id | id_education
```

- candidat_id_id is: null
- id_education has this value: `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection@000000003d585f990000000052235238`

Education table is empty

```
id | description | id_curriculum_vitae_id
```

My problem is with the `id_curriculum_vitae_id` and the `id_education`.